# How to set and fetch specific values for route params in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router-params

I have a set of routes like this:

```
/users/:type/:id
/users/admin/:id
/user/manager/:id
```

Now all of these use the same component. The catch is, admin and manager can see some extra stuff based on their `type`. Assuming I don't have a way to get these from user roles and then show the relevant information, can I use the `type` route param to identify if the user is `admin`, `manager` or any other type of user?

Essentially, in my init function, I am setting something like this:

```
this.userType = params.userType;
```

This will work in case of first route as we have a param set for type. Can I tell angular that the value `admin and manager` are actually the value of param `type`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use activatedroute to get the query params

first in the constructor you have to declare activateroute something like this

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute){}
```

Import activated route
and then on ngonit you write the following code to get the values

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params=>{
    this.user=params.type;
    this.id=params.id
})
```

Comment: For routes like `/users/admin/:id`, params.type will be undefined as angular is not aware that admin is a `type`.

Comment: the fetch the router url and 

in the router url 
do this 

if(this.url.includes("admin")){
//what ever operstion you want to do 
}